# Regex Pattern for a File Name

Tags: regex

A user can put a file in the server if the file name matches the following criteria:

It has to start with abc, then a dot, and a number.

```
Valid file names:

    abc.2344
    abc.111

Invalid:

    abcd.11
    abc.ab12
```

What would be the regex? I can't just use abc.*.

Comment: Whatever language you use, I'm quite sure it has docs about regexps. You *really* should read them before blindly using any regexp thrown at you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this:

```
^abc\.\d+$
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Perl regexp:

^abc\.\d+$

Answer (score 0):

`abc\.\d+` should match it

`\.` matches the `.`

`\d` matches any digit

Answer (score 0):

```
abc\.\d+
```

\d means any digit.

Comment: And `.` will match any character, unless you escape it with a backslash!

Answer (score 0):

Or a bit more verbose (= readable):

```
^abc\.[0-9]+$
```

where square brackets denote groups of characters.

By the way: The caret (^) means "start" and the dollar means "end" of the string in question (sometimes ^ and $ can mean start and end of a single line. It depends).

Answer (score 0):

\d+ and [0-9]+ still fall afoul of his requirement that "abcd.11" be invalid.

In Perl you could say:

`/^abcd.\d{3,}$/`

To indicate "abcd." followed by at least 3 digits. Not all regex languages support this syntax so inspect your documentation.

Comment: As far as I can see, he didn't limit the number of digits.

Comment: Aha, you appear to be correct. My mistake, I scanned over the d without registering the difference.

^abc\.\d+$ is correct.