# Regex Pattern Matching

Tags: regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regex Pattern for a File Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763005/regex-pattern-for-a-file-name)

A user can put a file in the server if the file name matches the following criteria:

It has to be abc or it should start with abc, then a dot, and a number.

```
Valid file names:    
abc
abc.2344    
abc.111

Invalid:    
abcd
abcd.11    
abc.ab12
```

What would be the regex? abc.\d+ doesn't have abc to be correct.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763005

Comment: Download Expresso, great tool for creating and testing regexes

Comment: Exact duplicate of the question Gumbo linked.

Comment: Almost exact; the exception is the use of "abc" without a trailing dot or digits.

Comment: @Greg: Ok. I should have said "Close enough to be considered exact - the poster should have edited the original instead of posting this duplicate one." Happy now? :-)

Answer (score 5):

```
abc(\.\d+)?
```

The question mark means optional.

Answer (score 1):

Make the latter part optional.

```
abc(\.\d+)?
```